# Bash replace '\n\n}' string in file

Tags: regex, bash, perl, awk, sed

I've got files repeatedly containing the string `\n\n}` and I need to replace such string with `\n}` (removing one of the two newlines).

Since such files are dynamically generated through a bash script, I need to embed replacing code inside the script.

I tried with the following commands, but it doesn't work:

```
cat file.tex | sed -e 's/\n\n}/\n}/g' # it doesn't work!
cat file.tex | perl -p00e 's/\n\n}/\n}/g' # it doesn't work!
cat file.tex | awk -v RS="" '{gsub (/\n\n}/, "\nb")}1' # it does work, but not for large files
```

Comment: [Useless use of `cat`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat)

Comment: In Perl, `-00` means to use paragraph mode, meaning that the each "line" that is read into `$_` ends with `\n\n+` (and not `\n` as per default line read). This means that there will never be a `}` after them. What you want is to slurp the input, i.e. `-0777`.

Comment: To complement @TLP's comment: analogously, `-v RS=""` in `awk` activates _paragraph_ mode too, so the `gsub` will never be able to match `\n\n`. Thus, the command is equivalent to `awk -v RS="" '1' file.tex`, which effectively simply removes empty lines.
To really read the _entire_ file, you'd have to use `-v RS='^$'` with _GNU_ `awk`, or, with BSD `awk`, something like `-v RS=$'\3'` (any _single_ char. not expected to be in the input).

Comment: @mklement0 all true and just to round it off: in non-gawk the robust, portable way to operate on a whole file is `awk '{wholeFile=wholeFile $0 RS} END{ do stuff with wholeFile }' file`.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't provide any sample input and expected output so it's a guess but maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
$ cat file
a
b

c

}
d

$ awk '/^$/{f=1;next} f{if(!/^}/)print "";f=0} 1' file
a
b

c
}
d
```

Comment: ++ for an efficient solution that does _not_ read the whole file into memory first.

Answer (score 1):

a way with sed:

```
sed -i -n ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n\n}/\n}/g;p' file.tex
```

details:

```
:a             # defines the label "a"
N              # append the next line to the pattern space
$!ba           # if it is not the last line, go to label a
s/\n\n}/\n}/g  # replace all \n\n} with \n}
p              # print
```

The i parameter will change the file in place.
The n parameter prevents to automatically print the lines.

Comment: Nice, but requires _GNU_ `sed`; a version without `-i`  that works with _BSD_ `sed` as well: `sed  -n -e ':a' -e 'N;$!ba' -e 's/\n\n}/\'$'\n''}/g;p' file.tex` (separate `-e` options needed to terminate label names; literal newline needed in replacement string). Sadly, when using  `-i` without a suffix, a single command that works with _both_ versions is _not_ possible. A _BSD_ `sed` command with `-i`: `sed -i '' -n -e ':a' -e 'N;$!ba' -e 's/\n\n}/\'$'\n''}/g;p' file.tex`. Since the OP mentions large files, it's worth stating explicitly that this solution reads the _whole_ file into memory.

Comment: @mklement0: indeed, there's probably a way (like a test `/\n[^}\n]/`) to free the memory when it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Nix-style line filters process the file *line-by-line*. Thus, you have to do something extra to process an expression which *spans* lines.

As mentioned by others, `'\n\n'` is simply an empty line and matches the regular expression `/^$/`. Perhaps the most efficient thing to do is to save each empty line until you know whether or not the next one will contain a close bracket at the beginning of the line.

```
cat file.tex | perl -ne 'if ( $b ) { print $b unless m/^\}/; undef $b; } if ( m/^$/ ) { $b=$_; } else { print; } END { print $b if $b; }'
```

And to clean it all up we add an END block, to process the case that the last line in the file is blank (and we want to keep it).

Comment: just to be clear, while it's true that line fiters process their input line by line, that does not include awk which is record-oriented, unlike sed, grep, etc. which are line-oriented. The issue the OP is having, however, is apparently that even his "records" (and we don't know what those are given no sample input) are too large to fit in memory.

Comment: Kudos for covering the edge case of a trailing empty line, but your `perl` command is broken: `$b` needs resetting in the `if ( $b )` branch, and the `elseif` must be a separate `if` statement: `cat file.tex | perl -ne 'if ($b) { print $b unless m/^\}/; $b=""; } if (m/^$/) { $b=$_; } else { print; } END { print $b if $b; }'`. In essence, this is the `perl` cousin of @EdMorton's  `awk` solution, so it too has the advantage of not slurping the entire file at once.
Ed: not reading the file as a whole is the only constraint I can detect in the question; don't see anything re record size.

Comment: @mklement0 the OP said `awk -v RS="" '...' # it does work, but not for large files` so he tried using records (paragraphs in this case) smaller than the whole file and it still was too large.

Comment: @EdMorton: I see - that's certainly possible, but here's my conspiracy theory: the OP tried it on a _small_ file first, and _mistakenly_ concluded that it worked based on reading the _entire_ file  (as we've established, what the command truly does is read _paragraphs_ and remove _all empty_ lines), but then abandoned the approach due to not wanting to apply it to the real, large files.

Comment: @mklement0, you're right. Resetting `$b` was in there once, until I "streamlined" it.

Comment: funny how often "streamlined" and "broke" are synonymous :-).

Comment: @EdMorton, no doubt :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
cat file.tex | sed -e 's/\\n\\n}/\\n}/g'
```

if `\n\n}` is written as raw string.

Or if it's new line:

```
cat file.tex | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n\n}/\n}/g'
```

> Another method:

if the first `\n` is **any** new line:

```
text=$(< file.tex)
text=${text//$'\n\n}'/$'\n}'}
printf "%s\n" "$text" #> file
```

If the first `\n` is an empty line:

```
text=$(< file.tex)
text=${text//$'\n\n\n}'/$'\n\n}'}
printf "%s\n" "$text" #> file
```

Comment: Judging by the OP's own solution attempts, it's fair to assume that _actual_ newlines must be matched, not _literal_ `\n` sequences.

Comment: Thanks for updating, but now you've effectively duplicated @Casimir et Hippolyte's solution, and the same caveats apply: _GNU_ `sed` required, whole file is read at once.

Comment: added another solution that will supposedly work everywhere, let me know if it has any limitations, @mklement0

Comment: This one works nicely, except that you needn't and shouldn't use `-e` with `echo` (the replacement used _actual_ newlines - nothing left to expand). You can improve the efficiency slightly with `text=$(< file.tex)`. Overall, however, the issue is still that the file is read into memory as a whole.

Comment: added your suggestion, @mklement0

Comment: Thanks, Jahid, but if you're using `printf`, please use `printf '%s\n' "$text"`, otherwise you'll again subject the string to interpretation of backslash escape sequences.

Answer (score 1):

This Perl command will do as you ask

```
perl -i -0777 -pe's/\n(?=\n})//g' file.tex
```

Comment: ++ for elegance, but note that the entire file is read _at once_, and judging by the OP's comment on their own `awk` command, they want to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to node you can use rexreplace

```
npm install -g regreplace
```

and then run

```
rexreplace '\n\n\}' '\n\}' myfile.txt
```

Of if you have more files in a dir `data` you can do

```
rexreplace '\n\n\}' '\n\}' data/*.txt
```